# ASP.NET MVC4 - Adding to ViewBag in more than one method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Let's say I have a controller with a method that returns a PartialView. If I want to add data to the ViewBag, must it all go inside the one method?

For example:

```
public PartialViewResult GetPage()
{
   ViewBag.Example = "Here is some text.";
   AddMoreToViewBag();
   return PartialView();
}

private void AddMoreToViewBag()
{
   ViewBag.Example2 = "More text";
}
```

In the above example, will both Example1 and Example2 be available to the PartialView that is returned?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: @bump - I like the way you think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the above example, will both Example1 and Example2 be available to
>   the PartialView that is returned?

Yes, it is available.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>A partial view inherits its ViewContext (which includes Viewbag) from the parent view, so yes, this will work.</strike>

**Revised:**

The ViewBag is attached to the ControllerContext, which is part of the controller object. That's how it is accessible within the Action-method. So any other method declared within the same controller will also have access to the same ControllerContext, and therefore the same ViewBag.

So your `AddMoreToViewBag()` method works as long as it's defined within the same controller, or a base-controller that the controller inherits from.

If, for some reason, you need to define `AddMoreToViewBag()` outside of the controller (or it's base) then you'll need to pass in the ViewContext as an argument to your method.

Comment: I don't think this is what he was asking.  He wants to know, if calling a function outside of the ActionResult will enable you to continue to add objects to the view bag.

Answer (score 1):

`ViewBag` is of type `dynamic` but, is internally an `System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject()`

It is declared like this:

```
dynamic ViewBag = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
```

which is why you can do :

```
ViewBag.Example = "Here is some text.";
```

or

```
private void AddMoreToViewBag()
{
  ViewBag.Example2 = "More text";
}
```

Both are available in `View`.

Comment: He wasn't asking how or why you can append different properties to a view bag. He wants to know, if calling a function outside of the ActionResult will enable you to continue to add objects to the view bag and if they will be available in the view.